# List files not having another file with suffix

Tags: find, zsh, ls, diff

Consider a directory with the following files:

```
file1
file1.suffix
file2
file3
file3.suffix
```

I need to list all files such that there doesn't exist another file having the same name and a known suffix. In the example above that would match only `file2`.

This is what i came up with:

```
diff --new-line-format= --unchanged-line-format= \
    <(ls -I '*.suffix' | sort) \
    <(ls *.suffix | sed 's/\(.*\)\.suffix/\1/' | sort)
```

Is there a simpler and shorter way?

### Edit 1

In my concrete case there's actually multiple suffixes (bind zone files /w dnssec):

```
example.org
example.org.jbk
example.org.jnl
example.org.signed
example.org.signed.jnl
example.com
```

I'm trying to list zones that don't have dnssec enabled, that is, files that don't have another file with `.signed` extension.

This is my attempt:

```
diff --new-line-format= --unchanged-line-format= \
    <(ls -I '*.jbk' -I '*.jnl' -I '*.signed' -I '*.signed.jnl' | sort) \
    <(ls *.signed | sed 's/\(.*\)\.signed/\1/' | sort)
```

Comment: could be there files with other suffixes like `file1.opt` and how should they be treated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob # for the first "^" below
ls -ld -- ^*.suffix(^e:'[[ -e $REPLY.suffix ]]':)
```

(or use `^*.*` instead of `^*.suffix` if you only want to consider the extension-less files, or, following the update to your question `*.(org|net|com)` or `^*.*.*` or `^*.(signed|jnl|jbk)`...)

That is list the non-`.suffix` files, for which `file.suffix` doesn't exist using the `e` glob qualifier to select files based on the `e`valuation of some code (where `$REPLY` contains the path of the file to  select).

Another approach using the `${a:|b}` array subtraction operator (mnemonic: elements of `a` *bar* those of `b`):

```
bare=(^*.suffix(N))
with_suffix=(*.suffix(N:r))
ls -ld -- ${bare:|with_suffix}
```

`ls -ld --` is only used as an example command here, you can use any other command or store the list in an array like:

```
without_suffix=(${bare:|with_suffix})
```

Comment: I had a feeling zsh would have some clever magic to handle this. I didn't know about the `e`-qualifier and it seems quite powerful. Here's my modified version: `^*.(signed|jnl|jbk)(e:'[[ ! -f "$REPLY.signed" ]]':)`.

Comment: @Joe. That works too. `[[ -e file ]]` is for whether the file exists. `-f` adds the additional requirement that it be a _regular_ file (and not other types of files like directory, socket, fifo, device...). If you only want to consider _regular_ files, you could add the `.` glob qualifier (or `-.` to allow symlinks to regular files).

Comment: Oh right i didn't realize you can negate any qualifier with `^`. That's handy! I think now it's the time to add `extendedglob` to my `.zshrc`.

Comment: @Joe, note that `^` to negate qualifiers doesn't require `extendedglob`, it's the `^` glob operator that does. Still `extendedglob` is useful for a variety of operators like `#` (equivalent of RE `*`), `##` (RE `+`), `(#i)` (case insensitive), `(#c3,9)` (RE `{3,9}`), `^` (not), `~` (except), and some used primarily in pattern matching more than globs.

Answer (score 3):

As your current files list has simple naming convention - here's short `ls` + `cut` + `uniq` approach:

```
ls -v1 * | cut -d'.' -f1 | uniq -u
```

Comment: I love this. It's short, concise and outside the box, but unfortunately doesn't solve my actual problem (see edit).

Comment: @Joe Try listing only the `.signed` file plus one that's there for every zone (`.jbk`?): `ls -v1 *.jbk *.signed | ...`

Comment: @Joe: The following `sed` expression works with the second example: `ls | sed -E ':a; s/\.(signed|jnl|jbk)$//; ta' | uniq -u`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if shorter, but rather straightforwardly in the shell (Bash and zsh quickly tested):

```
for f in * ; do 
    [[ $f != *.suffix ]] && ! [[ -f "$f.suffix" ]] && echo "$f"
done
```

(or replace `echo` with something sensible)

Or the same with multiple suffixes:

```
suffixes=(suffix postfix)
for f in * ; do 
    for s in "${suffixes[@]}" ; do 
        [[ $f == *".$s" ]] || [[ -f "$f.$s" ]] && continue 2
    done
    echo "$f"
done
```